# Delayed jQuery slideToggle animation

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a custom accordion menu. To display second-level options in the menu, I chose to use `slideToggle()`. For some reason, There is a delay between when they click and when the animation occurs.

[image]

This is evident when seen in contrast with another accordion menu on the same page... I found out that the function that is bound (on click) to the menu item gets executed almost immediately. The problem is that the `slideToggle` animation seems to start later than it should.

I believe this may be happening because of the way I am targeting the element that `slideToggle()` is being called on.

```
            var $expandableMenu = $(".expandable .level1");

            $expandableMenu.bind('click', function () {

                $(this).next().slideToggle(200, function () {
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
                });

            });
```

Maybe the problem is that `$(this).next()` is a slow way to target the element that I need to use `slideToggle()` on?

What are your thoughts?

**Edit:** I made a jsFiddle test case... Oddly enough the issue does not happen here. http://jsfiddle.net/nYZNP Still looking for the issue.

Comment: +1 just for the animation! That's a great way to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can better test your issue? Also, the pertaining markup would be useful as well. Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle replica of the markup and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/nYZNP/ Oddly enough, the issue does not occur in the fiddle.... hmm..

Comment: @ChrisB Have you timed how long it takes $(this).next() to run? You may be able to rule that out (or, confirm it as the problem) easily enough.

Comment: How did you create the animation?

Comment: Does the problem also occur with other versions of jQuery? Do you have a live site we can try it on?

Comment: @AndersLindén The animation is done using the jQuery framework

Comment: @AdrianWragg I don't know how to test how long it takes for $(this).next() to run. How can I do this?

Comment: @trojansdestroy I have ruled out the possibility of it being jQuery's fault. The version of jQuery does not affect this problem. Unfortunately I don't have a live site for anyone to try it on, but I've posted a fiddle that replicates the scenario.

Comment: @ChrisB (not tested this myself!) You could create an instance of Date() before and after, and then compare values? I believe there may be JavaScript performance tools that may also be able to help, but I've not used any myself.

Comment: How did you create the animated screenshot?

Comment: Using this program called LICEcap http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: Your answer might be here [answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981462/delayed-jquery-slidetoggle-animation

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying this on a mobile device, it may indeed take longer for the animation to start, as the device is waiting (even 200ms+) to make sure you are not attempting a double-tap. If this is the case you could go for libraries like [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/), which has a tap event or [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) which emulates tap events.

in terms of selector performance, `$(this).parent()` should be fine. In this case however, you could eliminate a few milliseconds by not writing and reading the variable first, like this:

```
       $(".expandable .level1").bind('click', function () {

            $(this).next().slideToggle(200, function () {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
            });
        });
```

Also, "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." ([jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)). Or in other words, `bind()` is deprecated!

And finally there is the general rule that filtering by **tag name** is faster than by classname or id, so `$("li.expandable .level1")` should be faster than `$(".expandable .level1")`.

Maybe you can also be more specific about the exact circumstances, such as browser/device or any other difference to your fiddle?

Comment: Alternate fastclick repo is from github's "dave1010", which I prefer.  You can see the difference between regular and fastclick (if any) interactively here:
http://3oheme.com/blog/2013/08/10/apply-fast-click-for-ios-to-your-website.html

Answer (score 0):

```
            $(this).next().slideToggle(200, "linear", function () {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
            });
```

Have you tried using a different easing option?

Also if you are experiencing this on a mobile device, the delay may be part of how mobile devices handle click events which may have an inherent delay of 50ms or more.